# How Kong can be integrated with Consul

Tags: microservices, consul, kong

I would like to know the use of Consul and its integration with Kong. 
I understand Kong can be used as an API gateway specifically for micro-service architecture. Correct me if I am wrong. I have read integration between Kong and Consul. But I am failing to understand the real usage of Consul.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Here explains how we can make this connection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67069619/how-to-use-kong-with-dns-resolver

Answer (score 3):

You can make Kong work with Consul by specifying the `dns_resolver` property (in the `kong.conf` configuration file) to point to your Consul server (or by setting the `KONG_DNS_RESOLVER=<xxx>` environment variable).

By doing so, you are forcing Kong to use Consul to resolve hostname addresses in the `upstream_url` of your APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have read few forums and I am little bit confused about use of Consul. Can you please share your knowledge.

Comment: It works only if Consul is used as DNS server, doesn't it? Does any workaround exist for Consul HTTP API?

Comment: So I am using Consul's dns and can resolve my services in consul using that. But when I configure Kong to use my service upstream url as well which basically means I have to dig SRV records as well. This approach does not seem practical since services can be launched on any host/port. Is there something I may be missing here?

Comment: @f-z-N Kong 0.10.x also supports SRV records.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67069619/how-to-use-kong-with-dns-resolver but this link says it will get issue until you add the database service to the consul and use it as KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database.service.consul.